# A Tool to atomize liquid in the milliliter range

Tags: experimental-chemistry

for some graduate project I'm trying to create a mist from some water based solution to apply it to a surface, basically the surface is solid but very gentle and I need to spray it with this solution as evenly as possible, I cannot apply the solution with a syringe and then spread it around since this will pattern the surface, also the volume applied to the surface is important, I need to spray 2ml+-0.5ml, spraying 4ml for example would be too much

I've looked into an air brush but I couldn't find a way to control the volume and I've looked into a spray bottle but the volume there is too big.
any advice or suggestion would be welcome for a tool that can do this would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into using an inkjet (salvaged from an old printer). They can produce a regular, directed stream of small droplets and have a capacity of at least several mL. You can power them and control their behavior electronically. There are probably inkjet printers available that print onto a fixed platen, so that would take care of the production aspects.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a [*perfume atomizer*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B45BUE), if the solution is compatible with the materials of the sprayer. *Measure* the volume supplied with each squirt; it should be quite consistent, due to the constant volume of the plunger.

You could also construct an atomizer from glass tubing, as is done with soda straws in this [Do-Science article](http://www.doscience.com/act_archive/jan99_activity/jan99.html). Again, I would suggest measuring the efficiency with which the spray is delivered... **there will be some over-spray and drifting with any atomizer.**